# Getting browser popup message error when executing any cells on Google Colab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-colaboratory, mozilla

I am unable to use colab. I was executing a notebook when I have received a popup message error saying:

Error

`Could not load the JavaScript files needed to display output.
This is probably because your Google account login access has expired or because third-party cookies are not allowed by your browser.
Please reload this page.`

DETAILS

I'm using Google Chrome version 80.0.3987.149
I have tried to restart runtime, reloaded the page, tried to execute notebook in incognito window, restarted the browser and it did not work.
So, I tried to use Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge and the error kept showing. Further, I changed my Google account, I tried 3 differents accounts and it didn't work.
I also allowed [*.] googleusercontent.com cookies in the Allow section and the third-party cookies are enable.

Comment: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/745/ might help.

Comment: I look up the process and I can't find nothing that says it's consuming 100% of the cpu, so I don't think that's it (https://files.slack.com/files-pri/TM8B1CGDC-F010GUCHL9E/image.png)

Answer (score 0):

well I had the same problem and tried all the things you tried and more crazy solutions but none worked , the magic thing that worked in the end was to open colab using any vpn !

Comment: Can you elaborate on "to openColab using any VPN"?

Comment: Use a VPN for your internet connection, then open Colab website.